# Service worker is not caching

Tags: javascript, service-worker, service-worker-config

When I test the following code and I go to the cache storage of the chrome devtools it  is empty. It worked at a moment and after changing the `cacheName` at a moment it stopped, not sure if it is related.

```
if ('serviceWorker' in navigator) {
    window.addEventListener('load', () => {
      navigator.serviceWorker
        .register('sw_cached_pages.js')
        .then(reg => console.log('Service Worker: Registered (Pages)'))
        .catch(err => console.log(`Service Worker: Error: ${err}`));
    });
  }
```

And here is the SW itself:

```
const cacheName = '00001';

const cacheAssets = [
  'accueil.php',
  'js/accueil.js',
  'inc/Headers.php',
  'inc/footer.php'
];

// Call Install Event
self.addEventListener('install', e => {
  console.log('Service Worker: Installed');

  e.waitUntil(
    caches
      .open(cacheName)
      .then(cache => {
        console.log(cache)
        console.log('Service Worker: Caching Files', cache);
        cache.addAll(cacheAssets);
      })
      .then(() => self.skipWaiting())
  );
});

// Call Activate Event
self.addEventListener('activate', e => {
  console.log('Service Worker: Activated');
  // Remove unwanted caches
  e.waitUntil(
    caches.keys().then(cacheNames => {
      return Promise.all(
        cacheNames.map(cache => {
          if (cache !== cacheName) {
            console.log('Service Worker: Clearing Old Cache');
            return caches.delete(cache);
          }
        })
      );
    })
  );
});

// Call Fetch Event
self.addEventListener('fetch', e => {
  console.log('Service Worker: Fetching');
  e.respondWith(fetch(e.request).catch(() => caches.match(e.request)));
});
```

Comment: Looks like you stil have your old service worker  running. Have you updated your service worker?

Comment: @lxhom I'm testing it at localhost and only updated the file locally. The service worker is being recognized as the version changes when I change `cacheName` but nothing appears when I click on the cache storage `00001`

Comment: Is there a cache named `00001` with 0 cached items or is there no cache at all?

Comment: @lxhom there is a cache named like that with no cached items in it

Answer (score 4):

Maybe the reason is that you have "Disable cache" checked in your browser's DevTools? That was the reason for a similar problem that I had.

Comment: Yeah, maybe Edge, Chrome, Firefox & other browsers should alert this in the error message...

Answer (score 0):

So the problem lies in this section:

```js
// Call Install Event
self.addEventListener('install', e => {
  console.log('Service Worker: Installed');

  e.waitUntil(
    caches
      .open(cacheName)
      .then(cache => {
        console.log(cache)
        console.log('Service Worker: Caching Files', cache);
        cache.addAll(cacheAssets); // <- here
      })
      .then(() => self.skipWaiting())
  );
});
```

It's super simple: `cache.addAll` returns a promise, and you don't wait for it. You just have to add a `return` before the `cache.addAll` statement, that'll pass the promise to the next `.then()` (`.then(() => self.skipWaiting())`).

By the way: A better solution would be to use await, because it'd make it more clear. It'd look like this:

```js
e.waitUntil(
  async () => {
    cache = await caches.open(cacheName);
    console.log('Service Worker: Caching Files', cache);
    await cache.addAll(cacheAssets);
    self.skipWaiting();
  }
);
```

Learning async/await is super helpful and would've made this much easier to debug.

Comment: I tried to apply it but I still have the same result :(

Comment: Then try the following code in the JS console on your page: `cache = await caches.open("00001"); await cache.addAll("/");` and look in the cache section in the devtools. If this works, then its probably a promise thats chained incorrectly. I'd highly recommend rewriting it with async/await, and you'll probably find the issue.